# Сумма цифр числа через данный алгоритм

Tags: c++

Задача: **В этой задаче вам будут даны несколько значений для которых нужно посчитать сумму цифр. Вам следует реализовать алгоритм который в цикле делит число на 10 и суммирует получаемые остатки (это и будут цифры, появляющиеся как бы задом-наперед). 
Входные данные имеют такой формат:

первая строка содержит число N - количество тестов которые нужно обработать;

следующие N строк содержат по три целых числа A B C, составляющих один тест;

для каждого теста нужно умножить A на B и добавить C (т.е. A * B + C) - после чего сосчитать сумму цифр результата.

Ответ должен содержать N результатов, разделенных пробелами.**

*входные данные:

3

11 9 1

14 90 232

111 15 111

ответ:*

1 16 21

Алгоритм через который должно это решаться:

1492 div 10 = 149 and 2 as a remainder
149 div 10 = 14 and 9 as a remainder

14 div 10 = 1 and 4 as a remainder
1 div 10 = 0 and 1 as a remainder

Можно сказать, что я ее решил, но не тем способом и неправильно, тк я не понимаю как мне убрать последнее число после каждого деления. Например: 111*15+111=1776. Я делю 1776 на 10 через % и забираю остаток 6, но как мне теперь делить число 177? и дальше числа 17 и 1 отдельно?

Я написал по другому, но и это не работает до конца правильно, некоторые ответы он выводит правильные - некоторые нет. Но лучше объясните как сделать по способу изложенному выше.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int a, b, c, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        int action = a * b + c;
        int sum = (action / 100) + (action % 10 / 10) + (action % 10);
        cout << sum << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @wololo там по другому решается же

Comment: Там как надо решается. В цикле `while (number)` находим остаток от деления на `10` и добавляем к общей сумме цифр числа `sum += number % 10;`, затем с помощью деления отсекаем от числа самую правую цифру `number /= 10;`. Цикл будет продолжаться, пока не исчерпаются все цифры числа.

Comment: у меня это не работает ```#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int n;
 cin >> n;

 for (int a, b, c, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  int number = a * b + c;
  int sum = 0;
  while (number) {
   sum += number % 10;
   number /= 10;
  }
  cout << sum << " ";
  return sum;
 }

 return 0;
}``` @wololo

Comment: Уберите строку `return sum;`

Comment: теперь работает, спасибо @wololo